# Closing fancybox on escape form iframe

Tags: fancybox

i know fancybox supports close on esc.  but when you have the form and focus on one of the text box, then you cannot press "esc" key again to close the fancybox.

anyone has a clue how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a **keyup** event that **triggers** Fancybox close: (haven't tested this myself)

```
$("input").keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) { //Escape button
     $.fancybox.close();
   }
});
```

Comment: Not really manually - you're using an in-built function of fancybox, all you're doing is checking if the ESC button is pressed within the input boxes/form

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();

or else follow this.

http://www.moorewebexposure.com/web-design/how-to-close-fancybox-from-an-iframe/